# How to use stored procedure in jqgid?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, jqgrid

I want to use stored procedure to fill my JqGrid. My stored procedure is below:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SubJqGridObisDataSP]
as begin
DECLARE @header AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@MetID AS bigint 
SELECT @header = 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([ObisInfoTranslateT]) 

     from MetContDB.dbo.tblMet AS met
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblMod AS mod on mod.ModID= met.ModID_FK  
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblGroupData As Gro on Gro.MetID_FK= met.MetID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisData as obisdata on     obisdata.GroupDataID_FK=Gro.GroupDataID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisInfo AS obisinfo on obisinfo.ObisInfoID=obisdata.ObisInfoID_FK
     join (select  max(GroupDataID) as maxgroupdata   from MetContDB.dbo.tblGroupData   where MetID_FK=@MetID) g on Gro.GroupDataID=g.maxgroupdata 
     where met.MetID=@MetID

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
DECLARE @DynamicPIVOT AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @DynamicPIVOT = 'SELECT ' + @header +
' FROM (
select 
obisdata.ObisData,
       obisinfo.[ObisInfoTranslateT]

      from MetContDB.dbo.tblMet AS met
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblMod AS mod on mod.ModID= met.ModID_FK  
     join MeterControlDB.dbo.tblGroupData As Gro on Gro.MetID_FK= met.MetID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisData as obisdata on obisdata.GroupDataID_FK=Gro.GroupDataID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisInfo AS obisinfo on obisinfo.ObisInfoID=obisdata.ObisInfoID_FK
     join(select 
           max(GroupDataID) as maxgroupdata
           from MeterControlDB.dbo.tblGroupData
        where MetID_FK=@MetID) g on Gro.GroupDataID=g.maxgroupdata 
        where met.MetID=@MetID) Books
PIVOT (MAX(ObisData) FOR [ObisInfoTranslateT] IN (' + @header + ')) Result;'

EXEC (@DynamicPIVOT)
end
```

But when i use this SP in my controller, I get error : output of Stored procedure is int?????
My output stored procedure is some row. controller:

```
MetContDBEntities ctnx = new MetContDBEntities();
var obisDatas = ctnx.SubJqGridObisDataSP(id).ToList();
```

my code before query is:

```
select obisdata.ObisData,obisinfo.ObisInfoTranslateT
      from MetContDB.dbo.tblMet AS met
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblMod AS mod on mod.ModID= met.ModID_FK  
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblGroupData As Gro on Gro.MetID_FK= met.MetID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisData as obisdata on obisdata.GroupDataID_FK=Gro.GroupDataID
     join MetContDB.dbo.tblObisInfo AS obisinfo on obisinfo.ObisInfoID=obisdata.ObisInfoID_FK
     join(select 
           max(GroupDataID) as maxgroupdata
           from MetContDB.dbo.tblGroupData
        where MetID_FK=39) g on Gro.GroupDataID=g.maxgroupdata 
        where met.MetID=39
```

Output of this:
[image]
I want to show like this:
[image]

With first query I can change pic1 to pic2 .

Comment: It seems to be pure SQL question which have no direct relation to jqGrid. It would be helpful if you would describe first **what should do the code** instead of just posted the code only. I'm not sure that you need to use `PIVOT` in the case. It's unclear why it's not enough to use simple aggregation here. Moreover instead of filling the SELECT statement in the string one could probably just use CTE (`WITH ...`). I suppose that you can define subquery using CTE *without* saving results in comma separated string and then use the subquery in the second/main query.

Comment: @Oleg because i have query that i want join some table in it. and show vertical result to horizontal. i write query for this but i don't know how to use this stroed procedure in jqgrid.

Comment: jqGrid is pure JavaScript product. It can make Ajax call of and URL which returns the JSON data. So it's not really important whether you use STORED PROCEDUREs on the backend or not. Is `EXEC [dbo].[SubJqGridObisDataSP]` work in SQL Management Studio? How the results looks like? You post two lines of code with `MetContDBEntities` and `SubJqGridObisDataSP` without any required details. It gives no information. I used to use `SqlCommand` with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, `ExecuteReader`, read the results and save there in the List of data. No `DBEntities` is required.

Comment: By the way jqGrid have `jqPivot` which allows to generate columns of `colModel` based on the input data. It collects the unique values and build the columns for every different value. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) or [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#pivot_grid)

Comment: By the way, if you really need to construct SQL statement in a string and execute it, one should use typically `sp_executesql` statements instead of `EXEC`. There are many reasons for it. SQL injection in EXEC is just one from there (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/18/exec-vs-sp-executesql.aspx), [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc966425.aspx) and [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for example).

Comment: Sorry, but which problem in query you have? I wrote you three comments with different questions and suggestions. I still don't understand what you do exactly. The first question was **Is EXEC [dbo].[SubJqGridObisDataSP] works if you execute it separately (in SQL Management Studio for example)?**. I wrote you that one don't need to use entity framework in general to execute stored procedure. I personally use `SqlCommand` with `CommandType.StoredProcedure` in such case. I recommended you to use replace `EXEC` to `sp_executesql ` in the last statement (`EXEC (@DynamicPIVOT)`) of your procedure.

Comment: What is your current question? Do you want that I show you how to use jqPivot to display the grid like on the second picture? In the case you should **describe** what more common format have the input data. What aggregation should be made on the data with *the same* `ObisInfoTranslateT`? You input data are `[{"ObisData":6, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "Hight"}, {"ObisData":3, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "Power"}]`. What should be displayed if there are more items, like `{"ObisData":5, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "Hight"}` for example additionally. Should be displayed `Max(6,5)` ->`6` or `Sum(6,5)` -> `11` ...?

Comment: One more thing which is still strange in the destination data from the picture 1: I don't see any property in the input data which would responsible to produce *the row* of data. It's x-dimentions in pivot. In other words: **could you include another input data (picture 1) which would produce *more as one* rows of output data (picture 2)?**

Comment: @Oleg My output query is like picture1 that i want to show like picture 2 Indeed i want column's "ObisTranslateT" be header and it maybe is different in some query with different header. so I can writed query that change picture 1 to picture 2 but i don't know how to use in jqgrid

Comment: Could you answer on my previous question: **could you include another input data (picture 1) which would produce more as one rows of output data (picture 2)?** To be able to use jqPivot the input data have to have at least 3 columns. The current input data `[{"ObisData":6, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "Hight"}, {"ObisData":3, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "Power"}]` will be converted in *one row*, but one have to display *the grid (the table)*.  Look at [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9). One need specify `xDimension` which is unknown for your current input data.

Comment: @Oleg yes If i understand your mean. but i don't want use header (ObisData ,ObisInfoTranslateT ). i want use second column's picture 1 for header's picture 2 . I see "https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9" but i think it can not help me

Comment: I understand that and because of that I suggest to use jqPivot which will converts the input data in another data and generate `colModel` to display picture 2. To be able to help you I need **another input data**. I asked you 3 times for it. If you don't answer on my questions I'll stop the discussion.

Comment: @Oleg  [{"ObisData":6, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "High"}, {"ObisData":3, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "water"},{"ObisData":644, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "count"},{"ObisData":9.39.3, "ObisInfoTranslateT": "serial"},{"ObisData":2012/02/02",ObisInfoTranslateT": "date"},]

Comment: The data produce **one row of data in the output grid (picture 1)**, isn't so?  Can you include the data which produce **more as one row in the output Grid**?

Comment: @Oleg no. output grid picture 1 produce more than one row.

Comment: I speak about the **picture 2**. All current data which you included will be converted **not in a grid, but in the grid with only one row**. The last data produce one row: [6, 3, 644, 9.39.3, 2012/02/02] with the column headers `colNames: ["High", "water", "count", "serial", "date"]`. It is no grid if it could be only one row. Moreover the pivot means that one use **one common aggregate function** (like `MAX(ObisData)` in the original stored procedure). The last data looks suspected. What is `9.39.3`? Which type of data? It is not a number. Moreover hot to apply MAX for such data type?

Comment: @Oleg yes I want it . show in one row.